# Error while creating table?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
-> (
-> "ID" NUMBER,
-> "NAME" VARCHAR2(30),
->  PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
-> )engine-INNODB;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"ID" NUMBER, "NAME" VARCHAR2(30),  PRIMARY KEY
>   ("ID") )engine-INNODB' at line 3

Can someone tell me what is that I am doing wrong here!!!!

Comment: Where did you see that you have to use double quotes when specifying column names? Also, `engine-INNODB` is `engine=InnoDB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE `DEPARTMENT` (
`ID` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: I like it how you changed from InnoDB to MyISAM, like a ninja :>

Comment: This solves the problem.I was able to create the table.

Answer (score 2):

The column names should not be in double quotes, and the database engine should use an "=" sign rather than a hyphen.